# Looping through a td

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know that there is the DRY principle and I would like to understand what is the best way to use it in this case:

Im doing a project where i have to color each raw of td's depending on a day (the days are not consistent).
but regarding the td's:
in each raw there are 3 td's.
I took the td elements and manually wrote if's and each time added 3 to the array of the td.
what will be the best way to approach it?

My code:

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth();
var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

if (day === 4 && month === 5) {
  td[3].style.background = "yellow";
  td[3].style.color = "black";
} else if (day === 6 && month === 5) {
  td[6].style.background = "yellow";
  td[6].style.color = "black";
} else if (day === 8 && month === 5) {
  td[9].style.background = "yellow";
  td[9].style.color = "black";
} else if (day === 13 && month === 4) {
  td[12].style.background = "yellow";
  td[12].style.color = "black";
}
```

Comment: Use a switch! http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: Have you considered attaching custom classes to those `<td>`s? For example, `day-*` where `*` is 4, 6, 8 or 13. Then you could just grab all elements with that class (if any) and apply the styles to them.

Comment: your indexings a bit inconsistent? day4 = td[3]. day6=td[6], day8 = td[9]? Is there any sort of relation between day number and td index?

Comment: @judgeja there is no logic for the days itself only for the rows. the days represent days for special events and they vary but the td goes like this: DATE[0],EVENT[1],OFFER[2], so the it goes always in 3's

Answer (score 2):

I'd apply a class instead which saves a small amount of re-writing.

CSS

```
.highlighted{
    background: yellow; 
    color: black;
}
```

Javascript

```
if (day === 4 && month === 5) {
  td[3].classList.add("highlighted")
}
else if(day === 6 && month === 5) {
  td[6].classList.add("highlighted")
}
else if(day === 8 && month === 5) {
  td[9].classList.add("highlighted")
}
else if(day === 13 && month === 4) {
  td[12].classList.add("highlighted")
}
```

If there is a relation between the day and the index, then you could bring your javascript down to something like...

```
if ((day === 4 && month === 5) || (day === 6 && month === 5) || (day === 8 && month === 5) || (day === 13 && month === 4) {
  td[day].classList.add("highlighted")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
//var days = [];
//days['5/4']=3, days['5/6']=6, days['5/8']=9, days['4/13']=12;
var days={'5/4': 3, '5/6': 6, '5/8': 9, '4/13': 12}; //this is more elegant, thanks to @Rick
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth();
var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
if(!!days[month + '/' + day]) //true if exist 
    td[days[month + '/' + day]].classList.add("highlighted");
```

Comment: The `days` variable is used as an object instead of an array here, so you could declare it as `var days = {}`, or declare *and* initialize it as `var days = {'5/4': 3, '5/6': 6, '5/8': 9, '4/13': 12};`.  But this is a very good approach.